# Windows script to delete and copy file to multiple directories

Tags: windows, batch-file

Scenario:

There are about 150 directories all with very similar path names, but one folder in that path differs between each entry. Examples below

```
d:\TSProfiles\coetzeed.TEST.V2\Desktop\
d:\TSProfiles\ronaldb.TEST.V2\Desktop\
d:\TSProfiles\mcondaldc.TEST.V2\Desktop\
```

I want to do the following on all those directories, but somehow account for those different folder names in each entry, without having to add all those directories into the script.

```
del d:\TSProfiles\coetzeed.TEST.V2\Desktop\accounts.exe   (deletes the old accounts.exe)
Copy d:\newdesktop\accounts.exe  d:\TSProfiles\coetzeed.TEST.V2\Desktop\  (copies the new accounts.exe to the destination folder
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the commandprompt in **one single line** do this:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %a in ('dir d:\TSProfiles\* /ad /b ') do 
    echo copy /Y d:\newdesktop\accounts.exe  "d:\tsprofiles\%a\Desktop"
```

I put in a echo so you can check if the command will work, remove it if you're happy.

the command dir /ad /b basically spits out just the foldernames (/ad)  without any humbug ( the /b stands or 'bare')

There is no need to have a `script` for this. It just runs fine directly form the command prompt. If you want to use this in a script don't forget to replace the single % with a double %% for varaible `a`, so `%a` becomes `%%a`

Comment: you have missed opening and closing bracket for `do`

Comment: No, I didn't.  I said 'on one line'

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
pushd "d:\TSProfiles\"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s /a:-d "*accounts.exe"') do (
 del "%%~F" /F /Q
 copy "d:\newdesktop\accounts.exe" "%%~dpF" /Y

)
popd
```